# delete data from a table -oracle PLS-00357 error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am using the below code to delete data from a table based on number of days that passed in as parameter. `Tablename, DateColumnName and Numberofdays` are parameter.

```
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM' || UPPER (TRIM (TabName)) || ' WHERE' || TRUNC(DATECOLUMN)  || '<= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - ' || NUMBEROFDAYS ;
```

but it throws me an error `PLS-00357: TABLE VIEW or Sequence reference 'TABLE_NAME' not allowed in this context.`

I expect the  plsql to process the query like this
`DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE DUE_DATE <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 5`
am i missing something?

Comment: Print out the statement that you're trying to execute to make sure it is what you think it is. From here it looks like it may be missing few spaces.

Comment: You simply need to add an extra spaces between `FROM` and quotation mark: `'DELETE FROM ' || ...`; and `WHERE` and quotation mark: `' WHERE ' ||`; 2) There is no need to use `UPPER()` function here, really; 3) It would be better to use bind variables in this case: `'<= :1 - :2' using TRUNC(SYSDATE), NUMBEROFDAYS;`

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. I tried.. again the same error.
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM ' || (TRIM(TabName)) || ' WHERE ' || TRUNC(DATECOLUMN)  || ' <= :1 - :2 ' using TRUNC(SYSDATE), NUMBEROFDAYS;

Comment: i fixed the issue it seems the way as how i call those proc 
previously i did PROC(TabName,DDATE)   - i just added quotes to it PROC('TabName','DDATE')
thanks Nicholos and Mustaccio